# robot framework - RIDE : unable to run scripts getting WebDriverException

Tags: robotframework

I tried to run the test scripts using Robot Framework RIDE

I am getting the exception as `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

I tried with firefox also then i am getting the error as `WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

The Test Script as below:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     CLM Registration Test Case
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           DatabaseLibrary

*** Variables ***
${MSISDN_NUMBER}    9300012067
@{QueryResult}
${Delay}          5s

*** Test Cases ***
Prepaid Retail Registration
    Login to CLM
    Change Language to English
    Click on Register Kit


*** Keywords ***
Login to CLM
    Open Browser    http://172.20.24.74/clm-ui/#/login/    ff
    Input Text    id=username    akurasa
    Input Password    id=password    Srija210$
    Click Button    css=.btn.btn-primary

Change Language to English
    Sleep    ${Delay}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']/ul[2]/li/a/span[2]    30s
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']/ul[2]/li/a/span[2]
    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id='top-navbar']//a[contains(text(),'English')]

Click on Register Kit
    Sleep    ${Delay}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    //a[contains(text(),'Register Kit')]    30s
    Click Element    xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Register Kit')]
```

for chrome only statement changed is

```
 Open Browser    http://172.20.24.74/clm-ui/#/login/    Chrome
```

Please any one help on this.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: The error message are self explanatory, you need to download "chromedirver" (For Chrome) or "geckodriver" (For firefox) and put the executable in a location which is available in PATH variable.

Comment: Hi, I saved all the drivers to the location - `D:\Robot_WorkSpace\CLM\Drivers`. I have given this path  in PATH environment variable as`D:\Robot_WorkSpace\CLM\Drivers\`. Still same issue exist

Comment: Hi, I tried another way, stored all the drivers in the path where test suite exists. when ran, it opened the chrome/ie browser but getting the error `chromedriver.exe has stopped working' and force fully need to click on close program button. please help me

Comment: Please share more details like, chromedriver version and browser version

Comment: webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<your Chrome driver path>'), you can specify the complete path here when you are launching chrome, 2nd thing, the error regarding "chromedriver.exe has stopped working" occurs for many reason, one of the common one being "URL is not properly framed". Can you recheck your URL

Comment: Hi Saurabh, i am using `chrome driver version 2.25` and `browser Version 54`. I have added `chromedriver.exe` path to Environment Variable `PATH`. Still issue exist

Comment: Hi again downloaded the latest version of chromedriver, solved the issue. thanks saurabh and waman for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting answer because to tell what exact steps i followed solved the issue.

I downloaded latest version of chrome driver and placed in C:\Python\Scripts folder.

Which solved the issue.

Thanks Saurabh and Waman for your time